# How to Auto pop-up a dialog AFTER the main form is shown?

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi XE3. Now I need to pop-up a dialog AFTER the main form is shown.

I try to put the codes in FormShow event handler of the main form, as follows:

```
    with TMyChildForm.Create(Self) do
    begin
      ShowModal();
      Free;
    end;
```

However, this will cause the ChildForm to be pop-up BEFORE the main form is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delay showing the popup form until AFTER `OnShow` has exited.  You can either:

- use a short timer.
- `PostMessage()` a custom window message to yourself.
- use `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread()` or `TTask` to call `TThread.Queue()`.
- use `TThread.ForceQueue()` (10.2 Tokyo and later only).

Comment: Or use FormActivate instead (it comes up *after* the form is made visible). If you only want it to occur at the FIRST instance, just add `OnFormActivate:=NIL` in your event handler.